# problem with ar, linking and undefined reference

Tags: linux, linker, undefined-reference, unix-ar

I have a software package consisting of some 500+ fortran .f files.  It is rather well organized into various subfolders, and there is one high level *compile script* which calls the various *Makefile*'s within the subfolders.

Using the PGI compiler, I am doing this on SLES 11.4 x86_64.

There are no compile errors.

The problem happens at the end, when linking trying to create the one executable file the result is the same 10 or so undefined references to various functions.  I have explored all the Makefile(s) and there are no missing statements in there, and for the stated undefined references their respective `.o` file is present within the `objects/` folder and I also recognize all those `.o` files are being used in the creation of the `.a` file.

There is a total of 3 `.a` files created during the entire compile, and after 50 or so of the however many .f files are compiled there is an `Updating whatever#.a` printed where a **subsequent running of `ar` happens**.  This happens many times for each of the `whatever1.a` and `whatever2.a` and `whatever3.a` over the duration of the compile.

Thing is, knowing there is no error within the Makefile best I can tell, I can trigger a recompile of just one .f which corresponds to one of the undefined references and when that `whatever#.a` file is updated and linked **that specific undefined reference goes away**.  So I tried doing this for the others and sometimes it works but some it does not, it almost seems by chance I was able to fix it this way for some of the undefined references.

The other major thing is with all object `.o` files created, if I simply remove all 3 `.a` files and run the compile script then only the `ar` happens to recreate those 3 `.a.` files followed by the final linking which then says a **whole slew of different undefined references**.

I believe the problem lies with the usage of `ar` of possibly the version of it and/or the operating system is bugged.  Anybody know the real cause and how to get around this?  I am thinking of modifying the compile script instead of linking with 3 `.a` files to just manually cause the linking with all the ~500 `.o` files and take `ar` out of this completely.

Is there some limit to the number of `.o` files that can be put into a `.a` file with `.ar` ?

Comment: It may be a sequencing problem with the three libraries — if you have `libA`, `libB` and `libC` listed in that order on the link line, it's possible that `libA` defines `undef1` but `libB` is the first place `undef1` is referenced, so the linker skipped over the definition in `libA` (it wasn't needed at the time it was scanning `libA`), and it was never found in `libB` or `libC`. You could repeat the libraries — list `-lA -lB -lC -lA -lB -lC` — on the linker line. If that works, or at least changes the undefined references, then this is the basic trouble. The fixing is tedious. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The simplest fix is to combine the three separate libraries into one composite `libABC` and link with just that (`-lABC`).  Otherwise, you're into chasing circular references across libraries, which is no fun at all.  Some versions of the GNU `ld` have the ability to [group libraries](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.34/ld/Options.html#Options) so that the loader automatically rescans the libraries in the group until no references can be satisfied.

Comment: is it required to do `ranlib` or do `ar s` ?  if `ar` is all that is done does that cause problems with the *symbol table* and could the *symbol table* within the `.a` files be the problem?

Comment: It depends on the platform, but usually neither `ranlib` nor a special invocation of `ar` is needed.  Normally, when you use `ar` to edit a library, it also updates the symbol table that `ranlib` would create.  However, there are probably some platforms (though I don't think Linux is usually one of them — but I've not used SLES recently) where it is necessary to use `ranlib` or explicitly tell `ar` to update the symbol table.

Comment: I do know that the undefined references are not cross pollinated so to speak between these 3 `.a` libs.  It says cannot find <function name>, where I know what `.o` file it is defined in and I know which of the 3 `.a` libs it gets `ar`'d in to.  But I will try your idea on monday, thanks.  I know it's not some missing 3rd party library in linux, it's all within this one software program which at most it links with math for sin/cos/tan that's about it.

Comment: Good luck. You may find `nm -Ag` on the libraries helpful. It will allow you to confirm what you think you know.  Running `ranlib` on the libraries can do no harm, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

got my source files to link finally.  The solution was to work from last to first for the order that the undefined references were printed...

I would go to that `/objects/whatever/` subfolder where those specific `.o` files resided that the undefined reference complained about.

I simply removed those `.o` files, then reran my compile script which calls a Makefile and it only recompiled those `.f` files and then did an `ar r` of those files into the existing `.a` library.  Then those specific undefined references disappeared.  I repeated this for the 10 to 15 undefined references that had initially emerged, eventually reaching success.

Doing `ar -s` or ranlib on the existing `.a` files did not help.  So I guess it was an order of compilation and include into the `.a` file that was the problem?  Because I know initially that all necessary `.o` files were in the three `.a` files.